# How to return default value if condition didn't find a value

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a query.

```
async function getConfig(configId, country) {
    return await db.config.findOne({
        attributes: ['id', 'version', ...],
        where: { id: configId },
        include: [
            {
                required: false,
                model: db.domain,
                attributes: ['domain'],
                where: {
                    country_code: country,
                    isActive: true,
                },
            },
        ],
    });
}
```

In config table has a value.

```
id | version
------------
1  | '1.1.1'
```

And in domain table has values.

```
id | domain | country | isActive | isDefault 
--------------------------------------------
1  | http:1 | us      | false    | null
2  | http:2 | us      | false    | null
3  | http:3 | us      | false    | null
4  | http:4 | us      | true     | true
```

If I call my function with parameters `const config = await getConfig(1, 'tr')` I have to get default result because my `domain` table doesn't have domain with country code `tr`. I want to return default value if my condition can't find value. How can i do it?

I want to get a result.

```
    "result": {
        "id": 1,
        "version": "1.1.1",
        "domain": [
            {
                "domain": "http:4",
            }
        ],
    }
```

But I got a result

```
    "result": {
        "id": 1,
        "version": "1.1.1",
        "domain": [],
    }
```

Comment: You can use `afterFind` hook and set default value if there isn't any. You can also add a scope and set the default value inside scope with condition.
Like `Config.addScope('withDefaultValue).findOne()`

Answer (score 0):

I would return your found result and if it isn't found, return your default. You should be able to get the general idea from this and attaching your result to `const found`:

```
async function getConfig(configId, country) {

const found = await db.config.findOne({
    attributes: ['id', 'version', ...],
    where: { id: configId },
    include: [
        {
            required: false,
            model: db.domain,
            attributes: ['domain'],
            where: {
                country_code: country,
                isActive: true,
            },
        },
    ],
});

  if (found) {
      return found
  }
  else {
      return defaultValue
  }
}
```

Comment: it's solution will not work because in `config` table has value. In `found` variable will value  of config.

Comment: You can access the info required by found.domain etc

Answer (score 0):

Sequelize doesn't have getters for associations so a solution should be about to do it in code (only if you don't need a `config` as a model instance outside this function):

```
async function getConfig(configId, country) {
    const config = await db.config.findOne({
        attributes: ['id', 'version', ...],
        where: { id: configId },
        include: [
            {
                required: false,
                model: db.domain,
                attributes: ['domain'],
                where: {
                    country_code: country,
                    isActive: true,
                },
            },
        ],
    });
  const plainConfig = config.get({ plain: true })
  if (!plainConfig.domains.length) {
    plainConfig.domains = [{
      // your default domain props here
    }]
  }
  return plainConfig
}
```